# Logistic function approximation of the real valued Riemann $\zeta(x)$ function

Tags: optimization, riemann-zeta, approximation-theory

Given the function:
$$f(x)=\dfrac{a}{1-b\exp(-cx)}+d$$
where: $a = 0.7071$, $b = 2.21$, $c = 0.7672$, $d = 0.2942$, I found the following inequality:
$$|\zeta(x) - f(x)|\lt \epsilon$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\ge2$, with $$\epsilon = 1.3\times10^{-3}$$ Among many functions, the $f(x)$ is the best for the $\zeta(x)$ approximation.
Why the logistic function added to a constant can give a good approximation of the $\zeta(x)$? Thanks.

Comment: von Neumann is said to have said, "With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk." I think the first part of the quote applies here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I agree. But only the logistic function gives a very good fit

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Do you accept to fit half an elephant with two parameters ? I really would appreciate your opinion about what I did.

Comment: $\sqrt{\rm elephant}$, I think.

Comment: @Claude, sorry, meant to ping you with that last comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. I enjoyed the $\sqrt{elephant}$, be sure. Thanks for the humor. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using integer values $2 \leq x \leq 10$, your model and brute force, I obtain something better using $$f(x)=\frac{0.661382}{1-2.20299 e^{-0.747951 x}}+0.338967$$ which shows a better distribution of residuals and much lower errors.

You should notice that $a+d$ is almost equal to $1$. So, rerunning the model as $$f(x)=\dfrac{a}{1-b\exp(-cx)}+(1-a)$$ I obtained $$f(x)=\frac{0.643976}{1-2.19926 e^{-0.740259 x}}+0.356024 $$ which as good as the previous using one less parameter.

We can still improve the model forcing $f(2)=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$ since the previous model gives $f(2)=1.64494$ while $\frac{\pi ^2}{6}=1.64493$. This will remove another parameter from the regression. For example, you could replace in the model $$b=\frac{\left(\pi ^2-6\right) e^{2 c}}{6 a+\pi ^2-6}$$ and stay with only two parameters $(a,c)$ to be tuned. Doing so, we obtain $$f(x)=\frac{0.644005}{1-2.19922 e^{-0.740264 x}}+0.355905 $$ which is still very good.

**Added to this answer**

Looking at a model $$g(x)=\frac{\zeta(2)}{\zeta(x)}=a \Big(1+b e^{-c(x-2)}\Big)$$ and imposing $g(2)=1$ and $g(\infty)=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$ leads to $$a=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}$$ $$b=\frac{6}{\pi ^2}-1$$ Imposing now that $g'(2)$ be exact leads to $$c=-\frac{36 \zeta '(2)}{\pi ^2 \left(\pi ^2-6\right)}=0.883751$$ whcih is not bad at all without any adjustment. Letting $c$ to be adjustable and using now the model $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{6}{\pi ^2}-1\right) e^{-c (x-2)}}$$ to approximate $\zeta(x)$, the optimum value is $c=0.831036$ and the fit is really good at the price of a single tunable parameter.

Comment: Very good, but why among more than two hundred functions, only the logistic approximates so good the $\zeta(x)$?

Comment: What software do you use and what are the  two hundred functions you tried ?

Comment: I used LabFit curve fitting software V 7.2.48

Comment: This does not tell me the functions which have been tested.

Comment: All the functions contained in the software. The logistic function is that having the best Chi square value using Levenberg Marquardt optimization algorithm.

Comment: To understand why, may I suggest you plot $\zeta(2)/\zeta(x)$ as a function of $x$ ?